# Securing an app engine java endpoints back end

Tags: java, database, security, google-app-engine

So we have a google endpoints project with a datastore. This datastore will contain information relevant to multiple parties.

We want to keep access secure (only receive calls from other, whitelisted services), and ensure that we have a role system so that our data is safe from unauthorized access. 
I know google supports OAuth with whitelisting, but I was wondering if anyone has some good sources for data protection techniques that work well with the app engine.

For example, is there a role system we can easily use on endpoints other than whitelisting, to ensure that not only the source is legit, but the credentials are as well?

Additionally, we are limited in the encryption of certain data. We may want to filter users based on age, so we cannot hash their birthdate. Same for gender and location. The combination of these might already lead to an identity, which we do not want.

Thanks and good day,

Dries